# Access Nested Data Using Firebase in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nsdictionary

Having trouble loading nested data from Firebase in Swift 3.

After 6 hours of struggle and reading anything I could find, I still have no solution. My database looks like this:

[image: firebase data]

The data is a bunch of questions, each of which has one or more answers. I can get the basic question data ok, but can't access the answer data.

In my code below you can see how I get the basic question data.   I am stuck as to how to access the set of answers that I have in hand when I fetch the Question.  I am trying to avoid another database lookup to fetch the answers because I get them when I fetch the question.  I show in the code what i tired and how it failed (compile or runtime).  Can't see how to get at the data i have in hand for answers

Here are the print results of the debug. You can see that in both attempts I successfully get the key (which I need) and I successfully get a value that looks just like a Dictionary but I am unable to use it as a Dictionary.

```
------------------
Attempt #1
------------------
answer (-KZwfXU9inu4ozSjVBwS, {
    isCorrect = 1;
    text = "sample text data";
})
------------------
key .... -KZwfXU9inu4ozSjVBwS
------------------
value ....{
    isCorrect = 1;
    text = "sample text data";
}
------------------

------------------
Attempt #2
------------------
key .... -KZwfXU9inu4ozSjVBwS
------------------
value ....{
    isCorrect = 1;
    text = "sample text data";
}
------------------
```

The code ....

```
    // point at the database
    let refDB  = FIRDatabase.database().reference(fromURL: firebaseDB_URL)
    // point at Questions
    let questionsRef = refDB.child("questions")
    // filter questions to where the TopicRef is equal to the one provided
     questionsRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "topicRef").queryEqual(toValue: topicRef).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with:  { (snapshot) in

        if snapshot.value is NSNull {
            print("load questions - none found")
        } else {
            for child in snapshot.children {

                let snap = child as! FIRDataSnapshot //each child is a snapshot

                if snap.value != nil {
                    let key = snap.key

                    // Skip if fail to get the dictionary
                    guard let dict = snap.value as! [String: Any]? else {
                        print("bad snapshot in load questions")
                        continue
                    }

                    // Get the basic question information
                    var text = ""
                    var imageURL = ""
                    var answers = [Answer]()

                    // make sure that we don't choke on missing data in question

                    // GET text
                    if let textx = dict["text"] as! String? {
                        text = textx
                    } else {
                        print("missing name in question \(key)")
                    }

                    // GET image URL
                    if let imageURLx = dict["url"] as! String? {
                        imageURL = imageURLx
                    } else {
                        print("no image URL in question \(key)")
                    }


                    // load the aswers
                       if let answerDict = dict["answers"] as!  NSDictionary? {
                        // Attempt #1
                        for answer in answerDict {
                            print("------------------")
                            print("Attempt #1")
                            print("------------------")
                            print("answer \(answer)")
                            let akey = answer.key
                            let avalue = answer.value
                            print("------------------")
                            print("key .... \(akey)")
                            print("------------------")
                            print("value ....\(avalue)")
                            print("------------------")

                            // Attempt 1A
                            /*  Try cast answer to Dictionary. FAILS
                                This fails to compile with "can not down cast from NSDictionary.Iterator.Element
                                to more optional type [String,: Any]"

                             if let newDict = answer as! [String: Any]? {

                             }
                            */

                            // Attempt 1B - tired to see if i could approach avalue as JSON - FAILS
                            /* This compiles - but crashes at runtime "Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryM' to 'NSData'"
                            do {
                                let JSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject( with: avalue as! Data, options:JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions(rawValue: 0))
                                print("JSON .... \(JSON)")
                            } catch let JSONError as NSError {
                                print("error")
                            } 
                            */

                            // Attempt 1C
                            // avalue looks like a dictionaty so try to use t like one
                            //  fails to compile - "type Any has no subscript members"
                            /*
                            let answerText = avalue["text"]
                            */


                            // Attempt 1D
                            /*  Since avalue looks like a Dictionary try to make it a Dictionary. FAILS
                             This fails to compile with "can not down cast from Any
                             to more optional type [String,: Any]"

                             if let newDict = avalue as! [String: Any]? {

                             }*/

                        }

                        print(" ")
                        // Attempt #2
                        for (key, value) in answerDict {

                            print("------------------")
                            print("Attempt #2")
                            print("------------------")
                            print("key .... \(key)")
                            print("------------------")
                            print("value ....\(value)")
                            print("------------------")

                            // This also fails to compile - cant downcast form Any to [String, Any]
                            /*
                            if let newDict = value as! [String: Any]? {

                            } */

                            // I likewise can not cast 'value' to anything at all.. The next bit below fails to compile with "cannot downcase from Any to more optional type NSDictionary
                            // Try to make the 'value' in to its own NSDictionay as it looks like a Dictionary
                            /*
                            if let newNSDictionary = value as! NSDictionary? {

                            }
                            */

                        }

                    }

                } else {
                    print("bad snap in trying to load questions")
                }

            }
        }
    })
```

I also tried to cast the original `dict["answers"]` to other things (besides NSDictionary), but all failed to compile or crashed at runtime.  dict["answers"] could be a bunch of answers so I need to iterate. The iteration works but I can only get key and value. I can NOT get at the inside of value - which at each iteration looks like a Dictionary. At runtime the crash tells me that the 'value' for `dict["answers"]` wants to be cast to NSDictionary. I have done this but now when I iterate the value at each iteration is type Any. I have not been able to cast 'value' at the iteration to anything I can use to get at the data for each answer.

```
if let answerDict = dict["answers"] as!  NSDictionary? {
```

Appreciate any pointers to use the value data I have in hand (in value) and can see in print but can not access the key/value pairs programatically.